# Erro 0 ao enviar mensagem por Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tenho um sistema de posts em PHP e Jquery, onde os usuários postam coisas. Ainda não foi liberado pra ninguém, por quero deixar tudo pronto, porém me deparei com um erro que anda acontecendo no sistema.

Quando eu estou em casa ele funciona normalmente, porém quando eu vou em uma internet com uma potência mais fraca, ele dá o seguinte erro:

> Error 0 - error Tipo de Erro: error

As vezes envia a mensagem e as vezes não, e mesmo assim o erro acontece.

PHP

```
$data = date('d/m/Y')." ".date('H:i:s');

$dia = date('d/m/Y');
$hora = date('H:i:s');

$horac = date('d/m/Y')." ".date('H:i:s');

$frase = addslashes($_POST['texto']);

$tipo = "1";

$query = "insert into postagens(texto, id_user, data, hora, horat, horac, tipo) values ('$frase','$usuario_id','$dia','$hora','$data','$horac','$tipo')";
$rs = $mysqli->query($query);
```

SEGUE O CÓDIGO DO JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iconCarregando = $('carregando');
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        if ($("#texto").val() == '') {
            $('#texto').select();
            return false;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            var serializeDados = $('#form').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'acoes.php?enviar=1',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'POST',
                data: serializeDados,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#result').html(iconCarregando);
                    $('#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //desabilito
                },
                complete: function() {

                },
                success: function(data, textStatus) {

                    $('#texto').val("");
                    $('#send').removeAttr('disabled'); //habilito


                    $("#success-alert").alert();
                    $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 400).slideUp(400, function() {
                        $("#success-alert").slideUp(400);
                    });

                },
                error: function(xhr, er) {
                    $('#form').html('<p class="destaque">Error ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + '<br />Tipo de erro: ' + er + '</p>')
                }
            });

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Fala ae cara, beleza? Tem como você colocar o código do PHP também pro pessoal analisar melhor o que tá acontecendo no server-side?

Comment: amigo é só um form com textarea, bem básicão mesmo...

Comment: me refiro ao arquivo acoes.php

Comment: coloquei o arquivo

Comment: Pode ser timeout, o erro cai aqui `error: function(xhr, er) {` certo?

Comment: sim, oq é isso?